# Group MySQL output using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have following Database table "userdata"

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+
| id |user    |name       | job     | image   |department |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+ 
|  1 | User1  | name1     |   sales | link1   | sales     |
|  2 | User2  | name2     |   markt | link2   | marktin   |
|  3 | User3  | name3     |   sales | link3   | sales     |
|  4 | User4  | name4     |   sales | link4   | sales     |
|  5 | User5  | name5     |   clark | link5   | admin     |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

I want to output result to show like this:-

```
Department name : - **Sales**
User1 Image    User3 Image   User4 Image

Name : User 01   Job : Sales
Name : User 03   Job : Sales
Name : User 04   Job : Sales

-----------------------------------

Department name : - **marktin**
User2 Image    

Name : User 02   Job : Sales

-----------------------------------

Department name : - **admin**
User5 Image    

Name : User 05   Job : Sales
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrPwg.jpg)

can you help me how write to php code ( i want to users group by there department wise and display users images above details.
Thank you

Comment: Please show user table structure, pivot table (many to many relationship table)?

Comment: all data store in single table.

Comment: Do you have any code to display the table? Grouping should be done by the SQL queries: `ORDER BY department, name`

Comment: Do you want this in PHP or MySQL?

Comment: There is a very not clean way to do this in MySQL using group_concat!! I suggest that you do it using PHP.

Comment: i want this by php

Comment: Then post your php code, not SQL schema, update this question to have PHP code and then we can help addressing your issue :)

Comment: I think you help "3 normalform"